# illuminate/bus packages were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require

Tags: composer-php, laravel-7, packagist, illuminate-container

Lavavel & PHP versions:

```
Laravel: 7
PHP: 7.4.30
```

I am trying to install `pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg` package using composer like so:

```
composer require pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg
```

On the first try the error message was this:

```
  Problem 1
    - pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg[7.8.0, ..., 7.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1.4 -> found league/flysystem[1.1.4, ..., 1.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 1.0.69 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
```

So I tried upgrading league/flysystem:

```
composer update league/flysystem
```

But after trying to install `pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg` the error message changed to this:

```
  Problem 1
    - pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg[7.8.0, ..., 7.x-dev] require illuminate/bus ^8.67 -> found illuminate/bus[v8.67.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
```

How do I fix this error? I tried installing `illuminate/bus`:

```
composer require illuminate/bus ^8.67
```

But it gave:

```
Root composer.json requires illuminate/bus ^8.67, found illuminate/bus[v8.67.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
```

After running `why-not`:

```
% composer why-not illuminate/bus ^8.67

andrey-helldar/laravel-app v1.0.1     requires illuminate/console (^6.0|^7.0)               
andrey-helldar/laravel-app v1.0.1     requires illuminate/filesystem (^6.0|^7.0)            
andrey-helldar/laravel-app v1.0.1     requires illuminate/support (^6.0|^7.0)               
kreait/laravel-firebase    2.2.0      requires illuminate/contracts (^5.8|^6.0|^7.0)        
kreait/laravel-firebase    2.2.0      requires illuminate/support (^5.8|^6.0|^7.0)          
laravel/socialite          v4.4.1     requires illuminate/http (~5.7.0|~5.8.0|^6.0|^7.0)    
laravel/socialite          v4.4.1     requires illuminate/support (~5.7.0|~5.8.0|^6.0|^7.0) 
illuminate/bus             v8.83.24   requires illuminate/contracts (^8.0)                  
herazika/server            dev-master requires laravel/framework (^7.0)                     
illuminate/bus             v8.83.24   requires illuminate/pipeline (^8.0)                   
illuminate/bus             v8.83.24   requires illuminate/support (^8.0)
```

Comment: Installing a specific package version is done by seperating the package name and the version constraint with a `:` or a space. Try using `composer require illuminate/bus ^8.67`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the `why-not` result output, many of the packages you currently use are not ready for Laravel v8, like `andrey-helldar/laravel-app` (which, in the currently used version v1.0.1, is three years old!) or `herazika/server` (which isn't even avaliable on Packagist). On the other hand, `illuminate/bus ^8.67` explicitly requires Laravel v8

Installing the package using `composer require pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg "7.5.*"` could help. That's one of the versions that is still compatible with Laravel v7. Otherwise, try to update your packages first - some of them are way too old to be compatible with any new package you want to use

Comment: Thanks, I managed to install it, but now it gives ```Target class [mail.manager] does not exist.``` when visiting a page. Guess I really need to update the libraries...

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command to find out **why** you can not install a certain package:

```bash
composer why-not <package> <version>
```

In your case:

```bash
composer why-not illuminate/bus ^8.67
```

Comment: Thanks, I ran it and then checked the output. It seems there are some packages that ```illuminate/bus``` wants version```^8.0 ``` and other want ```^5.8|^6.0|^7.0```. Running composer update would probably solve the issue, I will try it later.